# Getting Prepared/Planning

Tags: .net, project-planning

For the first time, I am trying to create a rather large .NET project. I think the largest one I have made so far was about 6 classes, but this one is already at 14. For the section I'm starting to work on, I'm having some trouble putting everything together in my head, which is what I normally do. I think it's just a little too complex for that. I want to plan it out, and I want some way to visualize it and be able to play with it and manipulate the structure easily. Is there any sort of (free) program I can use to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have access to a whiteboard? Software tools are great, but I've always found drawing it out by hand really helps me think through design problems. Just start with some boxes which represent the problem at a high level, then begin fleshing it out from there.

That, and I hear the marker smell is scientifically proven to increase creativity.

Answer (score 2):

Pen and paper is often good enough, because you don't really want to get to a state where you can't visualise your problem on a single sheet of paper.  When designing solutions, try to break the problem down into them down into smaller sub problems. Applied to class design, this is called the [Single Responsability Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Ideally, do it in a way so that the classes are independent, rather than coupled. If they have to be coupled, keep it as minimal a possible.  You'll end up with more but smaller classes that are easier to maintain and you'll need to keep less of the whole program in your head at one time.

A good (free) tool to visualize the dependencies in your codebase is [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/). It can be a bit overwhelming at first and needs a bit time invested to get the most out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio can make Class Diagrams.  (In the Add new Item dialog)

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider [astah](http://astah.change-vision.com/en/product/astah-community.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a GNU-licensed UML design tool: http://www.umlet.com/

UML Class Diagrams will help you figure out your object model.  The others (Sequence, Use Case) will help you plan to meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Good ole' pencil and *graph paper*.  Let's you line things up better, draw better boxes, draw straight lines and makes you feel like an engineer designing some high-tech piece of machinery, which in an abstract way you are.

Answer (score 0):

I agree highly with the pencil and paper method. In addition to doing a class diagram, which is something that's fairly common but gives a static view of elements of your solution, I like to do sequence diagrams. These help clarify the relationships and responsibilities between the classes and, importantly, help you identify just the methods that you need to implement.